# Example how to model stock price with Pareto distribution according to Mandelbrot and Taleb

Tags: distribution, pareto-distribution

There's a paper by B. Mandelbrot and N. Taleb [Mild vs Wild Randomness](https://users.math.yale.edu/~bbm3/web_pdfs/mildvswild.pdf) that says that Pareto distributions is a better fit for modelling price changes.

```
P(X>x) = Kx^-α
where P(X>x) is the probability of exceeding a variable x
and α is the asymptotic power law exponent for x large enough

α ~ 3 for stocks
```

Is there **a more detailed, practical example how it can be used**? To estimate price distribution from historical prices? Ideally with some scripts in Python, R, Java etc.

Comment: You need to look at maximum likelihood for fitting a power law distribution - sadly, this is non trivial due to the xmin xmax variables which are themselves troublesome to derrive, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Maximum_likelihood